# How to split a string with an integer into two variables?

Tags: python, casting

For example, is it possible to convert the input

```
x = 10hr
```

into something like

```
y = 10
z = hr
```

I considering slicing, but the individual parts of the string will never be of a fixed length -- for example, the base string could also be something like `365d` or `9minutes`.

I'm aware of `split()` and `re.match` which can separate items into a list/group based on delimitation. But I'm curious what the shortest way to split a string containing a string and an integer into two separate *variables* is, without having to reassign the elements of the list.

Comment: "But I'm curious what the shortest way to split a string containing a string and an integer into two separate variables is, without having to reassign the elements of the list." - do you have any reason to *expect* something shorter than `y, z = whatever_you_have_in_mind_that_gives_a_list(x)`? (Did you just not know you can do `y, z = some_2_element_list`?)

Comment: "I considering slicing, but the individual parts of the string will never be of a fixed length" This indicates that you need to calculate the length of the "number" part of your string.

Comment: Also, `split()` uses a delimiter, but `re.match()` doesn't have to. Rather, you tell it what part of the string to match with a regular expression and it returns that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use list comprehension and join it as a string

```
x='10hr'
digits="".join([i for i in x if not i.isalpha()])
letters="".join([i for i in x if i.isalpha()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need some fancy function or `regex` for your use case

```
 x = '10hr'
 i=0
 while x[i].isdigit():
     i+=1
```

The solution assumes that the string is going to be in format you have mentioned: 10hr, 365d, 9minutes, etc..
Above loop will get you the first index value `i` for the string part

```
>>i
2
>>x[:i]
'10'
>>x[i:]
'hr'
```

Comment: @martineau Thanks for letting me know about the indentation.. I did not notice it when I posted it